# write a function that has 1 argument, that returns two columns oftof sorted integers

Tags: python, function, iteration, user-defined

write the function oddEven(num) that has 1 argument, num, a positive integer no greater than 100. This function returns two columns, one of positive integers, and one for negative integers
I'm not sure what to do past the last line of code to get two columns.
import random

```
def oddEven(num):
    x=num
    a,b=[],[]
    for i in range(x):
        o= b.append(random.randomint(-50,50))
        if o % 2 == 0:
            a.append(o)
        else:
            b.append(o)
    a.sort()
    b.sort()
    return a,b

def main():
    y=eval(input('What # of integers would you like in this list?:'))
    list1, list2 = oddeven(y)
    print('even','odd')
    for i in range (min(len(odd),len(even)):
            print(odd[i],even[i])            
    if len(odd) != len(even):
```

Comment: How are the two lists related to the argument `num`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to have a title that reflects the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code you posted has a lot of problems, so you need to [edit] and clarify what exactly you're having difficulty with. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

1. The function you need is `random.randint` not `random.randomint`
2. You need major edits in your <s>code</s> logic:

   - Make 2 lists for odd and even
   - Append corresponding values to the respective lists
   - If you return inside the loop, it will run only once

My code:

```
import random

def oddEven(num):
    x = num
    a, b = [], []
    for i in range(x):
      o = random.randint(-50,50)
      if o % 2 == 0:
        a.append(o)
      else:
        b.append(o)
    a.sort
    b.sort()
    return a,b
print(oddEven(45))
```

Output:

```
([14, 48, -10, -6, 10, 36, 26, 34, -6, 8, -26, 
16, 22, -42, -40, 38, -32, -44, 14, -46, 36, 20, 30, 10, -42], 
[-47, -41, -35, -21, -15, -15, -9, -3, -3, -1, 
5, 7, 9, 11, 17, 21, 25, 27, 33, 49])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of code you describe.

```
import random

def oddEven(num):
    # create list of random numbers from -50 to 50 of length num
    l = [random.randint(-50, 50) for i in range(num)]

    # Split list l into even and odd elements
    odd = [x for x in l if x % 2 == 1]
    even = [x for x in l if x % 2 == 0]

    return odd, even

# Test
print(oddEven(20)) # ([-47, -45, -25, -25, 27, -45, 39, -19, -3, -33], [-18, -46, -8, -10, -28, -12, -30, -12, 0, -10])
```

Comment: Might want a little check to see if x is not 0, since 0 is divisible by all numbers except itself, it's neither even or odd

Comment: @incapaz according to Wikipedia zero is even [Parity of Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero)

Comment: ok then looks like I made a mistake, I just assumed that since it was divisible by everything except 0

Comment: @incapaz no problem.  As you see its just a matter of what the number is modulo 2.